# Google Map and navigation tab with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to add map inside a tab navigation but i have some issues doing that.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_group:
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_map:
                selectedFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                selectedFragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance();
                break;
        }

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    }
};
```

this is my navigation logic with tabs, when i trying to use MapFragment i'm not finding a way to return Fragment from class "MapFragment" to replace the "selectedFrament".

The MapFragment code:

```
 public static Fragment newInstance() {
    MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
    return fragment;
}
```

If i extends from Fragment the onMapReady is not called, so i'm tried another approach, i used a GoogleApiClient to call onMapReady method.

This is my MapFragment class

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

and the onCreate method.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
        mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
    }

    // Build the Play services client for use by the Fused Location Provider and the Places API.
    // Use the addApi() method to request the Google Places API and the Fused Location Provider.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
}
```

This brought me another problem, when the user click in same tab i have the following error "Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0" cause i'm creating the connection always, to avoid this issue i'm trying to close it in all the lifecycle methods... onPause, onStop etc..

```
 @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

It's working when the user click in another tab but if clicks in same tab i have the same error and app getting crashed.

What is the best way to do that and what the approach i have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do one thing , you can avoid click on same tab by checking following :

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
   // add your code here
}
```

so it will not load full fragment again.